# Tables Not Being Created?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created some SQL code to create 7 tables based off an ERD.

It seems to be extremely close to working, except that it says that

> column "inv_no" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

However, the table invoice which inv_no is in is created, and has the column inv_no so I am very confused how it does not exist to create the other table invoiceLine which requires inv_no as a foreign key.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice(

        inv_no          INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        cust_id         INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        inv_date        DATE            NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_invoice_inv_no PRIMARY KEY(inv_no),
CONSTRAINT FK_customer_cust_id FOREIGN KEY(cust_id) REFERENCES customer(cust_id)
);

CREATE TABLE invoiceLine(

        inv_line_no     INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        inv_line_qty    INTEGER         NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_invoiceLine_inv_line_no PRIMARY KEY(inv_line_no),
CONSTRAINT FK_invoice_inv_no FOREIGN KEY(inv_no) REFERENCES invoice(inv_no)
);
```

Again, the table in question is invoiceLine which seems to be dependent on inv_no in the invoice table.

If anyone can spot my error that would be great!

Comment: you dont have `inv_no` in your `invoiceline` table, you cannot add foreign key for missing column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is correct there is no column `inv_no` in invoiceline. You need to declare that column as well:

```
CREATE TABLE invoiceLine(
       inv_no          INTEGER         NOT NULL,
       inv_line_no     INTEGER         NOT NULL,
       inv_line_qty    INTEGER         NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_invoiceLine_inv_line_no PRIMARY KEY(inv_line_no),
CONSTRAINT FK_invoice_inv_no FOREIGN KEY(inv_no) REFERENCES invoice(inv_no)
);
```

Comment: I see your point. Quite obvious now. My follow up if you're willing to answer though is, my ERD has a 1 to M relationship from invoice to invoiceLine. I thought that in order for this relationship to work a foreign key restraint on inv_no was required?

Comment: @ZAX: you are absolutely right. But in order to *store* a 1:M relationship you must store the referenced PK value of the `1` table in the `M` table. You already did that between customer and invoice.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your invoiceline table read;

```
CREATE TABLE invoiceLine(

        inv_line_no     INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        inv_line_qty    INTEGER         NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_invoiceLine_inv_line_no PRIMARY KEY(inv_line_no),
CONSTRAINT FK_invoice_inv_no FOREIGN KEY(inv_line_no) REFERENCES invoice(inv_no)
);
```

**`inv_line_no` instead of `inv_no`**

Answer (score 0):

you may want to add the inv_no column to invoiceLine table before adding a foreign key constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE invoiceLine(

    inv_line_no     INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    inv_line_qty    INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    inv_no          Integer         Not Null,
CONSTRAINT PK_invoiceLine_inv_line_no PRIMARY KEY(inv_line_no),
CONSTRAINT FK_invoice_inv_no FOREIGN KEY(inv_no) REFERENCES invoice(inv_no)
);
```